# Desktop launcher Error in Java & LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

**What's my problem:**

It says there is a null pointer exception in my desktop launcher class even though I haven't really touched it other than add a title and change the width & height. The weird thing is I haven't touched it and I've called my program before.

[image: Error in Eclipse]

Desktop Launcher Code:

```
    package com.kymedgames.poopman.desktop;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
    import com.kymedgames.poopman.Game;

    public class DesktopLauncher {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "Poopman Adventures";
        config.width = 800;
        config.height = 600;
    new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);
}
}
```

My Application Listener class in my core package is named Game.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

Run my application on desktop. (Which I have done before.)

**How I'm trying to accomplish it:**

By pressing the run button on Eclipse and not touching my desktop launcher other than add a title, width & height.

**What I need help with:**

Fix this randomly occurring error.

**Am I a noob?**

Kind of.

Answer (score 1):

You have (or one of your dependencies has) a static constructor that is failing, and it's failing because it tries to dereference something that is null.

You can see where this is happening by using the Eclipse feature [Add Java Exception Breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-addexception_viewaction.htm). This is a way of setting a breakpoint that is hit whenever an exception of a specific type is thrown.

Add an exception breakpoint for `NullPointerException` and it should show you where in the code something is null in a static constructor.

Comment: Judging by the line number of DesktopLauncher, the offending static initializer is in the Game class. Check the `static { }` block in the Game class